# Carrierwave/Fog - Argument error, provider not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I'm using Carrierwave 0.5.3 and Fog to upload images to Amazon-S3.

The setup works smoothly when running locally, no errors.

But when running on Heroku, uploads fail with this message:

```
2011-03-31T12:53:46-07:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError ( is not a recognized storage provider):
2011-03-31T12:53:46-07:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/useditems_controller.rb:36:in `create'
```

I've got an initializer:

```
# /config/initializers/fog.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'secret',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'also secret',
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'jabberwocky'
end
```

And an uploader:

```
# /app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or ImageScience support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "useditems"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [220, 2000]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

I've traced the error message to Fog, and it seems that Fog, under Heroku, isn't getting the config info from the initializer. `:provider` is somehow empty. But I'm stumped as to how to fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using:

```
rails 3.0.4
heroku 1.19.1
fog 0.7.1
ruby 1.9.2 under rvm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was due to the fact that I had mistakenly added the initializer to the .gitignore-file. Thus, it was never uploaded to Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this for completeness...

After smashing my head against the wall for hours with this error message, I found out that I had this line at the beginning of the carrierwave initializer:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  ...
```

So the initializer was only considered in the test environment. After removing it, everything worked as expected.